# ruby: no such file or directory -- ./droidgap

Tags: android, ruby, cordova, cmd

Why do i get this error (ruby: no such file or directory -- ./droidgap) when trying to install/setup PhoneGap work-space using cmd or git bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "droidgap" command was deprecated out of the project as we wanted to remove the dependency on Ruby. You are better off following these setup instructions:

http://phonegap.com/start#android

Comment: Following that tutorial, there is no 'phonegap.js' to copy in the latest Phonegap repo...?

Comment: Yeah, that page has to get fixed. The latest download 1.5 changes the name to Cordova so that link is outdated. Brian was working on an update. I just got back from vacation.

Comment: I'm willing to help with the update (screen shots, edited guide) but first need to test the code that is to replace `package com.phonegap.helloworld`, `import com.phonegap.*` and `extend DroidGap` - what should this now be?