# Definitive version of Phonegap tutorial for Android

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a definitive tutorial for Phonegap with Android? The [existing one fails](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/start) to cover the whole Callback/Apache Cordova naming thing and the [deprecation of DroidGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007234/ruby-no-such-file-or-directory-droidgap) (featured in most PhoneGap forum answers suggesting `import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;`). [This helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384738/what-is-cordova-and-how-does-it-relate-to-phonegap), but I'm short of reading time (after spending a day and most of a night at this) - all I need to do is get a simple skeleton app working so I can start porting an [existing PhoneGap-based iOS app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/greenview/id508188193?mt=8) to Android.

Update: after much time spent fiddling with Eclipse and installing the necessary, the [latest guide](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android) or [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT02ytSSMII) still fall at the first hurdle for me - there's no PhoneGap for Android icon in Eclipse, and the Android project wizard now also appears to be broken... so I've ended up paying someone to do the porting from iOS to Android. Every encounter I've had with Eclipse has been fraught with errors - I simply don't have the time to fix them all!

Comment: +1 for the good question. I'd like to have the same information... I tried the official getting started guide, but following the tutorial step by step was an epic fail...

Comment: They just recently had a blog entry on the name confusion thingy: http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

Comment: Waiting for advice from Simon MacDonald at the second link (DroidGap deprecation), will post here when received...

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find that either when upgrading my apps to cordova-1.5.0  but I found my answers in the example app found in  the phonegap-phonegap-1.5.0-0-gde1960d.zip  It is in the folder phonegap-phonegap-de1960d/lib/android/example

Answer (score 1):

I also found the example contained in the `phonegap-phonegap-de1960d/lib/android/example` dir of the `phonegap-phonegap-1.5.0-0-gde1960d.zip` archive illuminating.

However, initially I had some problems (probably since I'm running Linux, and thus have a case-sensetive file system), but then I realized that I needed to rename two of the files to:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
src/org/apache/cordova/example/cordovaExample.java
```

(These files had their names in all lower case in the zip file.)

Answer (score 0):

cordova.js replaces phonegap.js as now is already widely know. for cordovawebview, it's an alternative design (webapp not over native app but embedded as secondary component) better than a replacement.